# Dividers inside OL list

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I'm trying to set-up a "reference document" section as part of a Webhelp Responsive website that I build from a DITA map. I want to obtain a typical document list, with unique reference number (typically a [1], [2], [3]...[N]) followed by the document information (doc number, title, etc...), and I would like to "separate" my list in several sections (like Manuals, Procedures, articles, etc...), but KEEPING the list counter flowing.

I noticed that I could insert a `<div>` in between two `<li></li>` element, and it renders properly, but this is not valid from a pure HTML point of view.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
ul.demo {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p>Default list:</p>
<ol>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <div style="margin-left: -20px; margin-top:20px; margin-bottom: 20px;">test divider</div>
  <li>Coca Cola</li>
</ol>

<p>Remove bullets, margin and padding:</p>
<ul class="demo">
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Coca Cola</li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Is there a "proper" way of doing this, without breaking the `<ol>` into separate lists and use an external counter with CSS for example (I want to keep the original counter, as this is the one used by the linking system in my DITA-HTML transformation...).

Comment: Just style a `<li class="divider"></li>` to contain the divider you like to use. (this will count as an item though). Otherwise you'll have to Macgyver something with javascript that applies the dividers after the DOM is rendered.

Comment: Yes I already thought about this, but as you say that will count as a "normal" list item, and I would prefer to keep the counter continuous... Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the divider is just for *styling* then a pseudo-element would work:

```css
ul.demo {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 0;
}

li.first::before {
  content: "--------- test divider -----------";
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul class="demo">
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li class="first">Coca Cola</li>
</ul>
```

You can futher enhance this will data-attributes

```css
ul.demo {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 0;
}

li.first::before {
  content: "-----" attr(data-type) "-----";
  display: block;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul class="demo">
  <li class="first" data-type="Beverages">Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li class="first" data-type="Soft Drinks">Coca Cola</li>
</ul>
```